# No Google Maps UI in Android Studio Emulator Extended Controls

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps, android-emulator, apple-m1

Emulator is displaying the old location settings in the extended controls and not the updated settings with the Google Maps option to select a single point or a route.

Screenshot [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bScCs.jpg)

Im currently running the latest build of Android studio (Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 2) on my m1 MacBook.

Ive got the same version of android studio and android emulator on my windows pc and the google map is being displayed , not exactly sure why this isnt the case on my MacBook.

Comment: I got the same problem, is there any solution for that? I tried x86 emulators without success. 
On my older intel chip based mac, all the arm64 emulators have google maps ui in location setting so this shouldn't be architecture related problem?

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: Unfortunately I’m still having the same issue, even on their latest update

Comment: It's fixed in the newest emulator version.